# Combining a large amount of netCDF files

Tags: python, netcdf, cdo-climate

I have a large folder of netCDF (.nc) files each one with a similar name. The data files contain variables of time, longitude, latitude, and monthly precipitation. The goal is to get the average monthly precipitation over X amount of years for each month. So in the end I would have 12 values representing the average monthly precipitation over X amount of years for each lat and long. Each file is the same location over many years.
Each file starts with the same name and ends in a “date.sub.nc” for example:

```
'data1.somthing.somthing1.avg_2d_Ind_Nx.200109.SUB.nc'
'data1.somthing.somthing1.avg_2d_Ind_Nx.200509.SUB.nc'
'data2.somthing.somthing1.avg_2d_Ind_Nx.201104.SUB.nc'
'data2.somthing.somthing1.avg_2d_Ind_Nx.201004.SUB.nc'
'data2.somthing.somthing1.avg_2d_Ind_Nx.201003.SUB.nc'
'data2.somthing.somthing1.avg_2d_Ind_Nx.201103.SUB.nc'
'data1.somthing.somthing1.avg_2d_Ind_Nx.201203.SUB.nc'
```

The ending is YearMonth.SUB.nc
What I have so far is:

```
array=[]
f = nc.MFDataset('data*.nc')
precp = f.variables['prectot']
time = f.variables['time']
array = f.variables['time','longitude','latitude','prectot']
```

I get a KeyError: ('time', 'longitude', 'latitude', 'prectot'). Is there a way to combine all this data so I am able to manipulate it?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine" the data?  It's already all in a single MFDataset object thanks to your `f = nc.MFDataset...` line.  In other words, the `f.variables['prectot'][:]` array is already a 3-D array with dimensions (time, latitude, longitude) containing the `prectot` values for each (time, latitude, longitude).

Comment: Also, re: your KeyError, `f.variables` is a Dict, and for any Dict you can only access one of its values at a time, i.e. `f.variables['time']` or `f.variables['longitude']`, not `f.variables['time', 'longitude']`.  But as my previous comment said, all you need anyways is `f.variables['prectot']` (provided I'm understanding you correctly).

Comment: I see, I was unsure on what MFDataset actually did. I tried glob.glob function but that just made a list of all my files. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @CharlieZender mentioned, `ncra` is the way to go here and I'll provide some more details on integrating that function into a Python script.  (PS - you can install NCO easily with Homebrew, e.g. http://alejandrosoto.net/blog/2014/01/22/setting-up-my-mac-for-scientific-research/)

```
import subprocess
import netCDF4
import glob
import numpy as np

for month in range(1,13):
    # Gather all the files for this month
    month_files = glob.glob('/path/to/files/*{0:0>2d}.SUB.nc'.format(month))


    # Using NCO functions ---------------
    avg_file = './precip_avg_{0:0>2d}.nc'.format(month)

    # Concatenate the files using ncrcat
    subprocess.call(['ncrcat'] + month_files + ['-O', avg_file])

    # Take the time (record) average using ncra 
    subprocess.call(['ncra', avg_file, '-O', avg_file])

    # Read in the monthly precip climatology file and do whatever now
    ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset(avg_file, 'r')
    pr = ncfile.variables['prectot'][:,:,:]
    ....

    # Using only Python -------------
    # Initialize an array to store monthly-mean precip for all years
    # let's presume we know the lat and lon dimensions (nlat, nlon)
    nyears = len(month_files)
    pr_arr = np.zeros([nyears,nlat,nlon], dtype='f4')

    # Populate pr_arr with each file's monthly-mean precip
    for idx, filename in enumerate(month_files):
        ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset(filename, 'r')
        pr = ncfile.variable['prectot'][:,:,:]  
        pr_arr[idx,:,:] = np.mean(pr, axis=0)
        ncfile.close()

    # Take the average along all years for a monthly climatology
    pr_clim = np.mean(pr_arr, axis=0)  # 2D now [lat,lon]
```

Comment: You can use pure Python to achieve the same result, NCO just greatly helps compress the time/memory demands.  I'll edit my answer to show you how to use only Python.

Comment: Two things: One, the for loop "for month in range(1,13):" is only taking the December month files. When changing the range from 1,13 to 1,12 it only takes the November month files. Would a another for loop above the fist one take care of this issue? Second, once I get into the "populate pr_arr" for loop it does not like the pr_arr[idx,:,:] =np.mean(pr, axis=0) saying "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,5) into shape (0,0)". Another question is what does "{0:0>2d}" actually do?

Comment: Strange about the for loop not working, it does on my end.  It should first pick out all January (month=1) files, then move on to the next month.  Try printing information after the for loops to help diagnose the issue.  What is the shape of `prectot` to begin with? Make sure you're inserting the dimension sizes of `nlat` and `nlon` into the initialization of pr_arr.  '{0:0>2d} pads integers with a leading 0, e.g. 1 becomes 01, which is how the filenames are structured. Check out more info on string formatting for extra details on this.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the loop. I added "append" function so now it looks like this.  month_files.append(glob.glob(*{0:0>2d}.SUB.nc'.format(month))). I saw when printing it would print all the file months 1 through 12 but seemed to only input the last set (December-12) into month_files. When you say assume the lat and lon does that mean I need to make an new array with the same lat and lons within my .nc files? prectot has a shape of (396L, 5L, 5L).

Comment: You just need to insert 5 where `nlat` and `nlon` are during the line where `pr_arr` is defined.  BTW, if the files are storing monthly-means to begin with, then the shape of `prectot` should be (1 x lat x lon)...I'm not sure where the 396 is coming from.  In that case, you don't need to compute a monthly mean as I've shown above. Just populate `pr_arr[idx,:,;]` with the monthly-mean precip from each month's file, i.e. `pr_arr[idx,:,:] = pr[0,:,:]`

Comment: The 396 is 33 years of data. (ie 396/12 = 33). Line with [ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset(filename, 'r')] is having issue. Produces 'TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, list found'.

Answer (score 3):

NCO does this with

```
ncra *.01.SUB.nc pcp_avg_01.nc
ncra *.02.SUB.nc pcp_avg_02.nc
...
ncra *.12.SUB.nc pcp_avg_12.nc
ncrcat pcp_avg_??.nc pcp_avg.nc
```

Of course the first twelve commands can be done with a Bash loop, reducing the total number of lines to less than five. If you prefer to script with python, you can check your answers with this. **ncra** docs [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncra).

Comment: I am using Enthought Canopy for python and I could not find or download the package NCO to get the ncra function. I would like to use it though.

Comment: I have installed NCO I think. when I run ncra *01.SUB.nc pcp_avg_01.nc it is outputting     {SyntaxError: invalid syntax     ncra *01.SUB.nc pcp_avg_01.nc} with the Caret pointing to S in SUB.nc not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You are running on Windows so shell globbing does not work. Replace *01.SUB.nc by the actual list of files to input. The manual can be helpful. See http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#Specifying-Input-Files

Answer (score 1):

The command **ymonmean** calculates the mean of calendar months in CDO.  Thus the task can be accomplished in two lines:

```
cdo mergetime data*.SUB.nc  merged.nc  # put files together into one series
cdo ymonmean merged.nc annual_cycle.nc # mean of all Jan,Feb etc.
```

cdo can also calculate the annual cycle of other statistics, ymonstd, ymonmax etc...  and the time units can be days or pentads as well as months. (e.g. ydaymean).